# Special Charecters issue while fetching data from sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am using this code to fetch the list of items from an asset library named Tech Experience on sharepoint 2010 using List WebService.

```
ListService.Lists objLists = new ListService.Lists();
                objLists.Credentials = Constant.credentials;
                objXMLDocument = new XmlDocument();
                objXMLDocument.LoadXml("<QueryOptions><IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns><Folder>Tech Experience</Folder><ViewAttributes Scope=\"RecursiveAll\" /></QueryOptions>");
                XmlNode objQueryOptions = objXMLDocument.DocumentElement;
                resultXml = objLists.GetListItems("Tech Experience", null, null, null, "100", objQueryOptions, null);
```

It throws this error "Error in xml Document" on executing the last line in the given code.

But if i change the asset library in the loadxml(ie from tech Exprience to something else) it works fine.

what I find till now is, the description of items available on this Asset Library contains some special characters like(',",<,>,&) which is creating problem.

Please correct me if i am wrong.

i can not ask my client not to use these characters while uploading new files.

please suggest how can i overcome this problem.

I will prefer a solution at the c# part if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, your client is sending you XML files that contain invalid XML. These characters have escape sequences in XML; are you sure you cannot ask your client to use them and send you well-formed XML?

Comment: The thing is sharepoint 2010 generates the xml, so there is no code which is generating xml. so the only i can think of now is to just install feature to sharepoint site which can remove these special characters.which i ll consider the last option.

Comment: You could load the file as a FileStream and try to replace invalid characters. The Regex for this would be most painful, as you need to take very good care not to mess up the valid XML in the process.

Comment: Found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/sharepoint2010general/thread/b409a8b7-652b-4a16-9eee-6af9c9259e65?stoAI=10&wa=wsignin1.0) on Google - are you sure you know which characters are causing the issue? Are items from the problematic folder showing up properly in SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

The "Tech Experience" list name... are you sure you're using the internal list name and not the display name?